# return a list of all datasets in a hdf file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, hdf

This may be a stupid question, but i have yet to find an answer in the pandas docs or elsewhere. The same question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24236252/read-the-properties-of-hdf-file-in-python). But the only answer was to look at the pandas docs, which as I stated don't provide an answer to this problem.

I want to be able to build an hdf file with several datasets. Once this hdf has been closed I would like to be able to list each of the datasets contained within. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

store = pd.HDFStore('test.h5')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,2), columns=list('AB')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,2), columns=list('AB')
store['df1'] = df1
store['df2'] = df2
print(store)
```

Returns:

```
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: test.h5
/df1           frame          (shape->[10,2])
/df2           frame          (shape->[10,2])
```

However if you close the hdf with `store.close()` and then attempt to read it using `pd.read_hdf()` the following error returns:

```
ValueError: key must be provided when HDF contains multiple datasets.
```

Is there a way to return a list of all these datasets?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there is.

```
store = pd.HDFStore('test.h5')
print(store)

<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: test.h5
/df1           frame          (shape->[10,2])
/df2           frame          (shape->[10,2])
```

Comment: You might also use [HDFStore.keys()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.HDFStore.keys.html), i.e. `store.keys()`